# how could I write this more succinctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails model called header that has a bunch of items. Both headers and items have an attribute called is_enabled and when the header's is_enabled is set to false, we want to update the items. I currently have this but it feels like it should just be a one-liner. How could I make it shorter?

```
after_save :update_menu_items

def update_items
  if self.is_enabled_changed?
    self.items.each do |item|
      if self.is_enabled==true
        item.is_enabled=true
      else
        item.is_enabled=false
      end
      item.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want an item's `is_enabled` attribute to match the parent header's attribute. In that case, the `self.is_enabled` check is unnecessary.

```
def update_items
  self.items.each{|i| i.update_attributes(is_enabled: self.is_enabled) } if self.is_enabled_changed?
end
```

In this case, `#update_attributes` triggers a save on each of the child items as it updates them.

Depending on how and how often the method is called, and how many child items will be associated, and how expensive that method is, you may not even want to check to see if the enabled attribute is changing:

```
def update_items
  self.items.each{|i| i.update_attributes(is_enabled: self.is_enabled) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, you could use the [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) method -- it doesn't call save because it doesn't instantiate the objects though, do you need it to call save?

```
after_save :update_menu_items

def update_items
  self.items.update_all(is_enabled: self.is_enabled) if self.is_enabled_changed?
end
```

Comment: If the callback was a `before_save`, the children would automatically save when `self` saved.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. save isn't called on related objects unless autosave is used (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. Autosave is default for many associations, but only when the child items are new, it will not autosave items that have already been persisted.